# python html MIME e-mail with embedded image and zip attachment display issues in outlook

Tags: python, email, outlook, mime-types, email-attachments

I am generating e-mails in python 3.6 via MIMEMultipart().  The e-mail is formatted via HTML and I am embedding a image and attaching a zip file.  If I only embed the image the e-mail looks great in Outlook 365 and I see the image correctly.  If I embed the image and attach my zip file, I get both attachments (image and zip) but the image doesn't populate and I just get a "x" for the image

I did find that it displays correctly in gmail but not Outlook in this case of both image and zip interestingly enough....

Code to add image and zip is below:

```py
def attach_zip(self, zip_filename):
        """   Attach a zip file to the email

              :param zip_filename: string path to the zip file to attach
              :type zip_filename: str
        """
        with open(zip_filename, 'rb') as fp:
            mime = MIMEApplication(fp.read(), self.sub_type)
            mime.add_header('X-Attachment-Id', 'zip2')
            mime.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=os.path.basename(zip_filename))
            mime.add_header('Content-ID', '<zip2>')
            mime.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'inline', filename=os.path.basename(zip_filename))
            self.msg.attach(mime)


def attach_picture(self, pic_filename):
        """   Attach a single picture to the email

              :param pic_filename: name of image to attach
              :type pic_filename: str
        """
        print('attaching image..{}'.format(pic_filename))
        with open(pic_filename, 'rb') as fp:
            img = MIMEImage(fp.read(), self.sub_type)
            img.add_header('X-Attachment-Id', 'image1')
            img.add_header('Content-ID', '<image1>')
            img.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'in-line', filename=pic_filename)
            self.msg.attach(img)
```

Any ideas? I feel like its a content header issue with Outlook? I have tried both web outlook and thick client and I get the same result.

Comment: How does the message HTML body refer to the images?

Comment: Currently I am using `<br>
<center><img src="cid:image1"> </center>
<br>` I tried it using the name i.e. cid:test.png and then changing the attach_picture above to match that name but no go either way.

Comment: That should be fine. Is that what you see when the message is received?

Comment: Nah I just get a X for the image in the body where it should be but the image is attached to the email.  If I do everything the same but don't attach the zip file too then it renders fine.

Comment: I don't mean visually, what do you see in the HTML body if you look at its source?

Comment: oh sure sorry, so in outlook thick client it looks like:  <center><img src="cid:image1"> </center>   if I look in the outlook web site and do a inspect it looks similar but interesting error: <img data-imagetype="AttachmentByCid" data-imageerror="AttNotFound" src="cid:image1">